# Check box with Label , click on sub label should open hyperlink: javascript

Tags: javascript, html

How to make a checkbox with containing text along with check box , like i have a Check box with label "I accept the "Term of Service"" in this text my Term of service should be make hyperlink , on clicking on Term of service text it should open a other HTML page,i have done Using below code , but using this code its check and uncheck the Check box , not opening hyper link .

```
 <input name="checkbox-0 " type="checkbox" data-iconpos="left" id="Chkterms">I accept the <a href="#terms-of-service">Terms of Services</a>. </label>
```

Answer (score 0):

call a javascript function in onchange and do inthat

Comment: actually i am new in Phone gap and java script so please refer me some snipet of code

Answer (score 0):

Remove the wrapping `label` to prevent clicks on your `a` tag to check the box.

See this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bigood/GWSgU/) for a demo.

Comment: here is my code the problem is when i removed the label then check box is not showing....    <div class="chkbox-large-text">
                                                    <label>
                                                    <input name="checkbox-0 " type="checkbox" data-iconpos="left" id="Chkterms">I accept the <a href="#terms-of-service">Terms of Services</a>. </label>
                                                    </div>

Comment: @dkBose The guilty might be your CSS, which could be applying style to   `inputs` only if they are descendants of `label`? As you didn't provided the css, I can't help you further than that.

Answer (score 0):

to be exact, this code works fine for me
just modified it to open google.com in a new page

```
<html>
 <input name="checkbox-0 " type="checkbox" data-iconpos="left" id="Chkterms">

 I accept the <a href="http://google.com" target=_blank>Terms of Services</a>.
</html>
```

Comment: have you able to show Check box with your code? and able to check and uncheck?

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you. I have put `label` as `<label for="Chkterms">`. And used `span` for clickable link.

**Note:**
Opening `#terms-of-service` will scroll the page to an element with id `terms-of-service` and not to terms-of-service page.

**[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mHbHv/3/)**